# PHPUnit doesn't recognize tests in given directory

Tags: php, oop, phpunit

I'm creating a project where I'm using composer to get all my dependencies. I also use phpunit, where I just migrated my project to phpunit 6.0. Before this change my phpunit always worked correctly.

Before this this I was using the `5.7.13` version.

I'm currently requiring the package in my `composer.json` like this:

```
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0"
  },
```

I let all my tests extend the `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` class instead of the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` class.

My configuration stayed the same, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         color="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         stopOnFailures="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit Tests">
            <directory>./tests/bas/ProjectName/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
├───src
│   └───bas
│       └───ProjectName
│           └───... source files
├───tests
│   └───bas
│       └───ProjectName
│           ├───...test files like "ExampleTest.php"
```

When opening up a terminal in the root of my project and entering the `phpunit` command, it gives the following message:

> PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from
>   C:\Users\Bas\Web_development\ProjectName\phpunit.xml
>
> Time: 30 ms, Memory: 4.00MB
>
> No tests executed!

I've already tried adding the `suffix="Test.php"` to the `directory` tag inside the phpunit configuration.

I also tried removing the `/vendor/` folder from Composer and installing the packages back by an `composer update` command.

All my test functions start with the `test` word.

---

With [the answer from John Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234464/2989034) i'm receiving the following error message:

```
dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../phpunit/phpunit" && pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
        # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
        # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
        # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
        if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
                dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
        fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/phpunit" "$@"
```

Comment: are there function with the right name (i believe they have to start with `test`) in the file?

Comment: @Nanne Yes there are.

Comment: are You on win?

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, Windows 10

Comment: Install current phpunit (https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) and then you can call just ```phpunit``` Requires PHP 7.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a composer to manage dependencies then when you run from the root of your project just `phpunit` you propably execute a global and old phpunit binary.

You just run tests with:

> PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Instead of global exec you should run local dependency with the command `php ./vendor/bin/phpunit`

Comment: I'm getting some kind of error message, i'm pasting it in my question.

Comment: You can not directly exec non-windows binaries.

Comment: How did my IDE did it before? I'm currently on IntelliJ

Comment: Pointing a phpunit.phar in IDE configuration or running from a global path? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `php "vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit"`